# How can I migrate users of existing production apk to newly deployed version at open beta testing environment?

Tags: android, testing, apk, version, beta-versions

I have very specific requirements wherein I would like to provide our latest version apk access to user through open beta testing and want to stop the version lying on prodcution. Challenge here is how can migrate user from production to beta new version?

Let's say I deploy version 10.1 at open beta and want to migrate existing user which are already using production app. If possible how can I do that?

How can I stop production version as restricting features?

Comment: is your user download your apk through playstore?

Answer (score 0):

No - it is not possible to disable a version of an APK, or to force users to upgrade.

From the Android Developer Docs on [app versioning](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html):

> The Android system does not use app version information to enforce
>   restrictions on upgrades, downgrades, or compatibility of third-party
>   apps. Instead, you are responsible for enforcing version restrictions
>   within your app or by informing users of the version restrictions and
>   limitations.

The closest you can get is checking the application version on the server side (either by manually passing the version or by inferring from the request message format) and restricting use of your API to newer versions of the app.